# Chrome extension event listener fires multiple of times

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**Introduction**

I've got a problem with my extension for Chrome. It supposed to show a small overlay popup window (created in jQuery) with search results from Google based on your text selection. Basically you should be able to highlight a text on any page, right click on it (context menu), click on "Search for 'selected keyword'" and a small window pops up in the same tab as an overlay with all search results from Google.

**The problem**

It works as described, HOWEVER only for the first time. When I'll highlight another keyword and search for it, extension still REMEMBERS previous keywords and throws 2 windows at the same time. And if I would search for another keyword that would give me 3 windows with 2 previous searches and a new one...

I've tried to remove listener in background script after it executes, but didn't work. It looks like the old listeners are there and they are replying for a request from content script. Can  I somehow remove them?

I've tried to put:

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.removeListener(listener);
```

at the end of getClickHandler() function but doesn't work.

I was also thinking that maybe this piece of code in background script is doing that, but not sure

```
return function(info, tab) {
```

Please, do you have any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

PS. This pop-up window cannot be closed at the moment and am aware of that. But you can always refresh the page to get a clean window. The problem is that the second time I will get 2 pop ups opened in the same time... and so on as described above.

Manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Easy search Accelerator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Easily search for anything...",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Background page / script (sample.js):

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": 'Search for "%s"',
    "contexts":['selection'],
    "onclick": getClickHandler()
});
function getClickHandler() {
    return function(info, tab) {

    var url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + info.selectionText;

    chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function listener(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "searchQuery");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.keywordRequest == "Yes")
        port.postMessage({keyword: url});
    });
});

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-1.7.2.min.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "frame.js" });

    });
  };
};
```

Content script (frame.js)

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "searchQuery"});
port.postMessage({keywordRequest: "Yes"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function listen(msg) {

  var test = msg.keyword;
  $("body").append("<div style=\"position: fixed;top: 20px;right: 20px;z-index: 9999;\"><iframe style=\"border:1px solid #868686;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);\" src=\""+ test +"\" width=328 HEIGHT=240></iframe></div>");
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ports should be used for long-lived "connections".

[`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) (content script) and [`chrome.extension.onRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-onRequest) (background) should be used in your case (**[`sendMessage`/`onMessage` instead of `*Request` in Chrome 20+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811554/chrome-extension-port-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does/11811936#11811936)**).

These methods can be used as follows:

- On extension initialisation: Bind a `onRequest` event in the background
- Content script: Fire `sendRequest(request_obj, response_func)`
- Background: Received the previous object. Do something, and invoke `response_func`.

---

PS. Are you really including jQuery, *just* for appending a string? If yes, I strongly recommend to drop jQuery and use vanilla JavaScript:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.cssText = "position: fixed;top: 20px;right: 20px;z-index: 9999;";
div.innerHTML = "<iframe style=\"border:1px solid #868686;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);\" src=\""+ test +"\" width=328 HEIGHT=240></iframe>";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```