# Chrome Extension: Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When trying to communicate between my Content- and Background Script I get the following errors:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'message' of undefined       
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

**background.js**

```
function onRequest(request, sender, callbackFunction) {
    console.log("Me (BS) became this Message:" + request.message);
    sendResponse({message: request.message})
};
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

**streamcloud.js**

```
function contactBackground(nachricht){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({message: nachricht}, function(response) {
        console.log("The Background Script got the following Message: " + response.message);
    });
}
```

and my **manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "InstantWatch - Dev",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.7",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },  
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "InstantWatch",
    "default_icon" : "icon.ico"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "streamcloud.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I found the solution to add an background_page: "background.html" with an empty background.html, but since background_page isn't supported since manifest_version: 2, I can't use that.

Comment: Another way, which solve my problem with exactly this same error: 


  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13565529/390747

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`sendMessage` and `onRequest` are **not compatible**.

If you need to support **Chrome 19 and earlier**, use **`onRequest`** and **`sendRequest`**:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Warning: Chrome 19- [receiver]
});
chrome.extension.sendRequest(message, optional_sendResponse);
```

---

For **Chrome 20 - 25**, use `chrome.extension.onMessage` and `chrome.extension.sendMessage`:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Chrome 20+
});
chrome.extension.sendMessage(message, optional_sendResponse);
```

---

For **Chrome 26+**, use [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage).

---

Note: As of Chrome 26, the deprecated methods are still supported, albeit undocumented. If you get a chance, update your extension to use the new methods, to ensure that your extension will still work in the future.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718294/938089?chrome-runtime-sendmessage-not-working-as-expected) for code to create a which is compatible with Chrome 20+.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

Use

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(onRequest);
```

Since you are using sendMessage and not sendRequest.

Message parsing has been updated in the new version of Chrome. sendRequest and onRequest are being deprecated. It is recommended to go with sendMessage and onMessage.

Refer docs for [message parsing between Content Script and Background](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: This applies to Chrome 20-25. In Chrome 26 the API changed, again. See [Rob W's answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11811936/3345375) as well as [peterthinking's answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18131296/3345375).