# Is it possible to trigger behavior in the content script from the popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Currently I am using message passing to send a request from my contentscript for data in localStorage and I am not having any issues with that, the content script is working as expected.

Can you do this in the other direction?

I have an object that exists in the content script that has a method called ".apply()" and I want to run it when the used clicks the option to do so.

I tried to make a listener in the content script like this:

```
var myLinker = new Linker();
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.method == "apply")
{
        myLinker.apply("nothing");
        alert("applied");

}
    else
      ; //Do nothing
```

And send requests to it like this:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "apply"}, function(){
    alert("Tried to request");
});
```

I get that it is a bit of a hack, but it is the only thing I could think of, and it doesn't even work =/

Is there a way to do this?

I am pretty sure I could just inject new code into the page from the popup (I think I saw an api function for that), and then run stuff, but that would take more memory and just feels like a bad way to do it, because you would basically have the exact same code twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send a message from the extension to a content script, use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.extension.sendRequest`.

Because [`sendRequest` has been superseded by `onMessage` in Chrome 20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811936), there's no official documentation for `sendRequest` any more. The documentation for `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` can be found [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage). Please note that these events cannot be mixed, use either `*Request` *or* `*Message`.

Comment: Edited because I realized I misread what you said, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use this: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage

Content scripts live within the DOM of the page.  And each page that is open within Chrome has a tab ID associated with it -- http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-tabs.Tab

Let's say you want to send the {method: "apply"} to a page that was just opened in a new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { method: "apply" });
});
```

There are other events/methods to get the specific Tab you want to send the message to.  I think there's one called getCurrent to send to the currently selected tab, check out the docs for that.

Comment: When using `null` for `tab.id`, the current tab is selected.