# Chrome extension regarding injected script + localstorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am puzzling my way through my first 'putting it all together' Chrome extension, I'll describe what I am trying to do and then how I have been going about it with some script excerpts:

1. I have an options.html page and an options.js script that lets the user set a url in a textfield -- this gets stored using localStorage.

> ```
> function load_options() {
>    var repl_adurl = localStorage["repl_adurl"];
>    default_img.src = repl_adurl;
>    tf_default_ad.value = repl_adurl;
> }
>
> function save_options() {
>    var tf_ad = document.getElementById("tf_default_ad");
>    localStorage["repl_adurl"] = tf_ad.value;
> }
>
> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
>    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', save_options);
> });
>
> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load_options );
> ```

1. My contentscript injects a script 'myscript' into the page ( so it can have access to the img elements from the page's html )

> ```
> var s = document.createElement('script');
> s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("myscript.js");
> console.log( s.src );
> (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
> s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
> ```

1. myscript.js is *supposed* to somehow grab the local storage data and that determines how the image elements are manipulated.

I don't have any trouble grabbing the images from the html source, but I cannot seem to access the localStorage data. I realize it must have to do with the two scripts having different environments but I am unsure of how to overcome this issue -- as far as I know I need to have myscript.js injected from contentscript.js because contentscript.js doesn't have access to the html source.

Hopefully somebody here can suggest something I am missing.

Thank you, I appreciate any help you can offer!

-Andy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: You do not need an injected script to access the page's DOM (`<img>` elements). The DOM is already available to the content script.

Content scripts cannot directly access the `localStorage` of the extension's process, you need to implement a communication channel between the background page and the content script in order to achieve this. Fortunately, Chrome offers a simple [message passing API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging) for this purpose.

I suggest to use the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API instead of `localStorage`. The advantage of `chrome.storage` is that it's available to content scripts, which allows you to read/set values without a background page. Currently, your code looks quite manageable, so switching from the synchronous `localStorage` to the asynchronous `chrome.storage` API is doable.

Regardless of your choice, the content script's code has to read/write the preferences asynchronously:

```
// Example of preference name, used in the following two content script examples
var key = 'adurl';

// Example using message passing:
chrome.extension.sendMessage({type:'getPref',key:key}, function(result) {
    // Do something with result
});
// Example using chrome.storage:
chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(items) {
    var result = items[key];
    // Do something with result
});
```

As you can see, there's hardly any difference between the two. However, to get the first to work, you also have to add more logic to the background page:

```
// Background page
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.type === 'getPref') {
        var result = localStorage.getItem(message.key);
        sendResponse(result);
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if you want to switch to `chrome.storage`, the logic in your options page has to be slightly rewritten, because the current code (using `localStorage`) is synchronous, while `chrome.storage` is asynchronous:

```
// Options page
function load_options() {
   chrome.storage.local.get('repl_adurl', function(items) {
       var repl_adurl = items.repl_adurl;
       default_img.src = repl_adurl;
       tf_default_ad.value = repl_adurl;
   });
}
function save_options() {
   var tf_ad = document.getElementById('tf_default_ad');
   chrome.storage.local.set({
       repl_adurl: tf_ad.value
   });
}
```

### Documentation

- [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) (method [get](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#type-StorageArea), method [set](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#type-StorageArea))
- [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging) (note: this page uses `chrome.runtime` instead `chrome.extension`. For backwards-compatibility with Chrome 25-, use `chrome.extension` ([example using both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718066/chrome-runtime-sendmessage-not-working-as-expected/15718294#15718294%20chrome.runtime.sendMessage%20not%20working%20as%20expected%22%22)))
- [A simple and practical explanation of synchronous vs asynchronous ft. Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available/11689804#11689804)

Comment: Thank you, I located where I got the info for having to inject a second file to gain access of the DOM. It was this post, but looking closer at it I see my mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script

Comment: I just needed to provide 'tabs' permissions for my contentscript.js to be able to manipulate the DOM, I could access the img elements but changes I tried to make had no affect until I provide 'tabs' permission. I also appreciate the tip about using the chrome API for storage and I am making changes in that direction. Thanks!