# POST request on Facebook.com in Chrome Extension fails

Tags: ajax, facebook, google-chrome-extension, content-script, content-security-policy

I have a Chrome Extension that sends AJAX POST with some data on every page.

The problem is that, Facebook block the AJAX request resulting this:

> Refused to connect to
>   'URL_HERE' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src
>   https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net
>   http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:*
>   https://*.akamaihd.net ws://*.facebook.com:* http://*.akamaihd.net".

How to send AJAX call to my server on that page also?

I am new to making Chrome Extensions, please tell me if anything is possible. I am using Content Scripts. Not sure if something can be done with background pages.

Also, is there some place I can use to store data in Chrome Extension while using content scripts?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to perform a cross-origin request when the page's CSP interferes is through a background page. You can find a complete example at [Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest using background pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7699773/938089).

> Also, is there some place I can use to store data in Chrome Extension while using content scripts?

Use the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API, or use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and `localStorage`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875798/938089) for a more detailed explanation and sample code.