# Google Chrome Extension Cross domain AJAX and Content-Security-Policy

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am developing a Google Chrome Extensions which fetches title and description from each site and send to the server using jQuery AJAX. I am using manifest version 2 and added permissions for all http and https sites. The Ajax call was working fine with all sites.

Last day I found an error which prevented the code from sending ajax to server. To be accurate facebook.com was not allowing me to send cross domain request as they are using the HTTP header Content-Security-Policy(CSP). I think this is not related to the CSP of extension.
I am using Google Chrome version 25.0.1364.160.

Is this CSP Header breaking the cross-domain request capability of the Chrome extensions ?
Is there any workaround ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST request on Facebook.com in Chrome Extension fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011185/post-request-on-facebook-com-in-chrome-extension-fails)

Comment: Thanks @RobW. Anyway Google Chrome version > 25 seems to be working fine with CSP enabled sites also.