# Where and when should MessagePassing API methods be invoked?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to accessing localStorage in content scripts, so I use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) (manifest v2). But I'm not so clear about one thing : where & when should `chrome.extension.onMessage` (which is in my options.js) and `chrome.extension.sendMessage` (in contentscript.js) be invoked?

For me I use jQuery and I wrap both them in the `$(document).ready(function() { //... }`. But the extension will only run without exceptions when the options page and the injected page are opened at the same time, else it would give a exception like

`*Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.*`

I searched Stack Overflow for a while and find that some people use [background_page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2), but I think I just need a options page, not a background page. Is the background html/js really necessary that options page should use them together?

Comment: Related: [Chrome extension regarding injected script + localstorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869183/chrome-extension-regarding-injected-script-localstorage/15875798#15875798 "Chrome extension regarding injected script + localstorage")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in options page are only active when the options page is running. So, when options page is closed it won't be able to receive messages.

You need to use [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html). Options page and background page uses the same localStorage, so you can access localStorage in background page without any problem.

Comment: Do u mean I need background page and options page both together?

Comment: Yes, you need options page for saving and displaying options to user and you need background page to communicate the settings to contentScript