# Displaying a localstorage variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

This question pertian to a Chrome Browser Extension (js Injection and localstorage)

Okay, I swear I have searched for days for the answer to this question (or one similar) and either there is not one or I am a complete moron about this topic.

Here is what I'm trying to do and it should be something very simple.  I am not new to chrome extensions but VERY new to creating options for the addon....

I simply want to display a saved piece of data visually.  For example...

Let's say the localstorage has stored an input text field (username) as "MyUsername".

I want to recall and display that visually in the page that i am injecting code to.  Here is an example...

The Code (inject.js):

```
var el = document.createElement('div'),
    b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    otherlib = false,
el.setAttribute("id", "vBar");
    el.style.position = 'fixed';
    msg = 'just testing';
    return showMsg();
```

Where you see  "msg = 'just testing';"... I just want it to display the username (from local storage) instead of 'just testing'.

The Output should just look like...

> **MyUsername**

Please tell me I'm not an idiot.  I can't figure out why it's not displaying the result.  It simply shows...

> **Undefined**

Comment: What is `showMsg()`? You haven't posted it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension regarding injected script + localstorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869183/chrome-extension-regarding-injected-script-localstorage)

Comment: I hardly see that page as being a duplicate.  The only thing it has in common is that it's about a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

When a content script accesses `localStorage`, it will access the storage belonging to the domain of the page where the script was injected. That's probably not what you want in this case.

You can use the [`chrome.storage` api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) instead, that will allow you to share information across all your extension scripts instances and your background page.

Comment: Not sure I explained myself correctly.  The localstorage saved the text area data and I simply want to be able to display that data inside the part of the js file that reasd...

msg = 'just testing';

How would I recall that data in order to display it?

Note that this script injects the content into the page you are viewing in the browser. (creating a small notification bar that appears at the bottome of the page)

Comment: @user2284703 please include in your question the code where you are saving the data to localStorage, the code you wrote to attempt to retrieve it and doesn't work, and the code where you are setting the text for your injected element.

Comment: chrome.storage api really do the trick and makes your extension development simpler. Or check answer from the link provided by Rob W, it shows how to access background page's localStorage