# What should be the valid 'matches' pattern in 'external_connectable' in manifest.json of chrome extension?

Tags: regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

From the link :
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable

I want to know what should be my valid matches pattern.

There is little confusion inside 'reference' block :

> Patterns cannot include wildcard domains nor subdomains of (effective) top level domains; `*://google.com/*` and `http://*.chromium.org/*` are valid, while `<all_urls>`, `http://*/*`, `*://*.com/*`, and even `http://*.appspot.com/*` are not.

In above line what is the pattern difference between

```
http://*.chromium.org/*
```

and

```
http://*.appspot.com/*
```

And So why first one is valid and second one is not?

Edit : when i provide `'*://*.mywebsite.com'` it reflected as invalid manifest, however the same pattern is given as sample code for external_connectable, means should be a valid valid pattern, But actually validation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"appspot.com" is an *effective top level domain* listed in the [public suffix list](http://publicsuffix.org/list/). That means that "appspot.com" is treated like a TLD, something like ".co.uk" or ".com".

Further, there is a small bug in the code example in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable), `"https://*.google.com"` should be `"https://*.google.com/"` or `"https://*.google.com/*"`. A valid [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) requires a slash to denote the path, omission of it is forbidden.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can u please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720602/chrome-runtime-is-undefined. I really need the answer of linked question.