# Basic google chrome extension message passing not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to get message passing for a chrome extension to work but console.log(response) gives me undefined. I've looked at the docs for message passing and on stackoverflow, but in my case it won't work. I am at a loss as to why.

myscript.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return true;
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
      return true;
 });
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "nameasf",
  "description": "asfasaf",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://somedomain.com/"
  ],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://somedomain.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension: Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811554/chrome-extension-port-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the obsolete **`chrome.extension.sendRequest`**.
Use **[`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage)** instead.

(Note: You are already using the new **[`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** so you don't have to change anything on the listener side.)

---

<sub>A couple of sidenotes:</sub>

- <sub>For the code presented here you don't need any permission (especially not the powerful `tabs` permission).</sub>
- <sub>And it is a good idea to use non-persistent background pages (a.k.a. **[event-pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**) whenever possible as they are considerably more resource-friendly.</sub>

Comment: Ah, yes, excessive cutting and pasting from various sources screwed it up for me. :)
Anyway, the original problem was that I reloaded the extension with an "extension reloader" isntead of reloading it from chrome://extensions. It needed permission reloading as well it seems.