# Messaging problems between content script and background script (WebExtensions)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently trying to write a browser extension that catches all mailto links, instead of letting them being opened by the default mail application. The mechanism can be enabled and disabled using a simple toggle button.
When my extension loads everything seems to work, but I get a `Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`. Then when I use the toggle button to disable and enable it again I get the following:

```
23:52:15.247 function sendMsgToTabs(msg)  background.js:16:9
23:52:15.256 this.sendMsgToTabs(...) is undefined  background.js:17
23:52:15.302 Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.  (unknown)
23:53:29.347 TypeError: this._recipeManager is null[Learn More]  LoginManagerParent.jsm:77:9
```

**Edit**: And the disabling doesn't seem to work properly in the content script. The click handler is not properly removed for some reason...

[image]

So what could be causing all these errors? I checked `this.sendMsgToTabs` in the debugger and it actually isn't undefined. I also don't have any unusual sites open, so I don't understand why there is a connection problem.

I've only tested my code in Firefox for now. But people say Chrome's API is essentially the same. Here is my code:

**background.js**

```
'use strict'
class MyWebExtensionBackend {
    constructor() {
        this.icons = {
            enabled: '/icons/on.png',
            disabled: '/icons/off.png'
        }
        this.isEnabled = true
        browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(this.toggle.bind(this)) //toolbar button
        browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.msgListener.bind(this))
        this.enable()
    }
    enable() {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon({ path: this.icons.enabled })
        this.isEnabled = true
        console.log(this.sendMsgToTabs)
        this.sendMsgToTabs({isEnabled: this.isEnabled}).catch(console.error)
    }
    disable() {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon({ path: this.icons.disabled })
        this.isEnabled = false
        this.sendMsgToTabs({isEnabled: this.isEnabled}).catch(console.error)
    }
    toggle() {
        if (this.isEnabled)
            this.disable()
        else
            this.enable()
    }
    sendMsgToTabs(msg) {
        return browser.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
            let msgPromises = []
            for (let tab of tabs) {
                let msgPromise = browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg)
                msgPromises.push(msgPromise)
            }
            return Promise.all(msgPromises)
        })
    }
    msgListener(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(msg.link)
        /* browser.notifications.create({ // doesn't work
            "type": "basic",
            "iconUrl": browser.extension.getURL("icons/on.png"),
            "title": 'url opened',
            "message": msg.link
        }); */
    }
}

let myWebExtensionBackend = new MyWebExtensionBackend()
```

**content-script.js**

```
'use strict'
class MyWebExtensionFrontend {
    constructor() {
        this.isEnabled = false
        browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.msgListener.bind(this))
    }
    linkHandler(event) {
        if (event.target.tagName !== 'A')
            return
        let link = event.target.href
        if (link.startsWith('mailto:')) {
            event.preventDefault() // doesn't appear to have an effect
            console.log(link)
            browser.runtime.sendMessage({'link': link}).catch(console.error)
            //using a promise here felt kind of wrong 
            //because event handler functions can't really deal with that 
            //from what I can tell
            return false  // doesn't appear to have an effect
        }
    }
    enable() {
        console.log('enable frontend')
        window.addEventListener('click', this.linkHandler.bind(this))
        this.isEnabled = true
    }
    disable() {
        console.log('disable frontend')
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.linkHandler.bind(this))
        this.isEnabled = false
    }
    msgListener(req) {
        if (req.isEnabled)
            this.enable()
        else 
            this.disable()
        return Promise.resolve({res: ''})
    }
}

let myWebExtensionFrontend = new MyWebExtensionFrontend()
```

**manifest.json**

```
{

  "description": "A basic toggle button",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "toggle-button",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/TODO",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/on.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/on.png"
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure why is the error. But your messages actually have been sent between content script and background script.

Comment: Well, I'm not too sure about that. I don't think that it actually works for all tabs, otherwise I wouldn't get the connection error, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code. One is specific to WebExtensions, another is specific to DOM and JavaScript.

#### Issue 1: Return value of asynchronous methods in WebExtensions API

In Firefox, WebExtensions are available at two namespaces, `chrome.` and `browser.`. `chrome.` is designed to behave as close to Chrome's extension API, whereas `browser.` has some enhancements. In particular, the asynchronous `browser.` APIs may return a promise. The promise is only returned if the method is not called with a callback function. If it does receive a callback as parameter, the `browser.` API behaves like `chrome.`. Here are some examples:

```js
// These have a callback and return undefined.
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { /* ... */ });
browser.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { /* ... */ });

chrome.tabs.query({}); // No callback, returns undefined (this is quite useless).
browser.tabs.query({}); // No callback, returns a Promise<Array>.

browser.tabs.query({}).then(function(tabs) { /* ... */});
```

Note that the error message that you received showed that the *return value* is undefined:

```js
this.sendMsgToTabs(...) is undefined
```

If the method was undefined (as you thought), Firefox would print the following error:

```js
this.sendMsgToTabs is not a function
```

The fix for your case is to use promises as follows:

```js
sendMsgToTabs(msg) {
    // Note: Changed ", tabs =>" to ").then(tabs =>"
    return browser.tabs.query({}).then(tabs => {
        let msgPromises = []
        for (let tab of tabs) {
            let msgPromise = browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg)
            msgPromises.push(msgPromise)
        }
        return Promise.all(msgPromises)
    });
}
```

If there is any tab without a content script, the promise will be rejected though. If you don't care about the return value of the promise, add the following after `let msgPromise`:

```js
msgPromise = msgPromise.catch(() => {}); // Ignore errors.
```

#### Issue 2: Using .bind() with addEventListener / removeEventListener

Your code looks like this:

```js
// your enable() function:
window.addEventListener('click', this.linkHandler.bind(this))

// your disable() function:
window.removeEventListener('click', this.linkHandler.bind(this))
```

The issue with this is that [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a *new* function. So when the `enable()` method is called, a new function is created and used as an event listener. When `disable()` is called, a new function is created and passed to `removeEventListener`. Since this new function is distinct from any other function (the previous parameter to `addEventListener` in particular), the result is that the click handler is not removed.

There are three ways to register DOM events with the desired `this` value:

1. At the construction of the class, replace the instance method with a bound function:

   ```js
   // In the constructor:
   this.linkHandler = this.linkHandler.bind(this);

   // In your enable() function:
   window.addEventListener('click', this.linkHandler);

   // In your disable() function:
   window.removeEventListener('click', this.linkHandler);
   ```
2. At the call of `enable()` create a bound function if needed:

   ```js
   // In your enable() function:
   if (!this.linkHandlerBound) {
       this.linkHandlerBound = this.linkHandler.bind(this);
   }
   window.addEventListener('click', this.linkHandlerBound);

   // In your disable() function:
   window.removeEventListener('click', this.linkHandlerBound);
   // If wanted (but not needed), run: this.linkHandlerBound = null;
   ```
3. Pass an object with the [`handleEvent` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener#handleEvent()):

   ```js
   // A method of your class
   handleEvent(event) {
       if (event.type === 'click') {
           this.linkHandler(event);
       }
   }

   // In your enable() function:
   window.addEventListener('click', this);

   // In your disable() function:
   window.removeEventListener('click', this);
   ```

   Note, do *not* make the similar mistake of defining the object with the `handleEvent` method as follows:

   ```js
   // Do NOT do this! You won't be able to remove the listener because
   // you did not store a reference to the event handler object.
   window.addEventListener('click', {
       handleEvent: this.linkHandler.bind(this)
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you haven't shared how you handle connections but you may want to check [Long-lived connections](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) to distinguish different types of connections and how to have an established connection.

As mentioned in the given link,

> When establishing a connection, each end is given a `runtime.Port` object which is used for sending and receiving messages through that connection.

Here is a sample on how you open a channel from a content script, and send and listen for messages:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  if (msg.question == "Who's there?")
    port.postMessage({answer: "Madame"});
  else if (msg.question == "Madame who?")
    port.postMessage({answer: "Madame... Bovary"});
});
```

Furthermore, you may want to also check the suggested solutions in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811936) and see which works for you.

Comment: It's all in my code. I'm using tabs.sendMessage and runtime.SendMessage. There is no additional code, I shared everything except the icons. I'd rather fix my existing code than making it even more complicated.